# How to change <input/>'s placeholder color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I tried the following with the stylesheet and `<input/>` yet the color of the placeholder still has not changed and stays at the default color. Am I doing it incorrectly?

my css stylesheet:

```
#input-field {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

:-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    blue;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    blue;
   opacity:  1;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    blue;
   opacity:  1;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    blue;
}
```

And my `<input/>`:

```
  <input
    className="form-control"
    id="input-field"
    placeholder='Change This Color'
  />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

webkit needed two colons `::`

```css
#input-field {
  font-family: serif;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: blue;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: blue; 
   opacity:  1;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: blue;  
   opacity:  1;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: blue;  
}
```

```html
<input
    className="form-control"
    id="input-field"
    placeholder='Change This Color'
  />
```

to change the font-family add `font-family: serif;` to `#input-field`

Comment: Tried `font-family: "Helvetica Neue";` but the placeholder didn't change

Comment: Repeat the font-family line in each of the placeholder definitions in the CSS

Comment: also, is `font-family: "Helvetica Neue";` in the right format?

Comment: It's right, as long as you have the font installed on your computer it should show up

Answer (score 1):

In your Html Page

```
<input
class="form-control"
id="input-field"
placeholder='Change This Color'
/>
```

in your css page

```
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  width: 250px;
  font-family:Helvetica Neue;
}
```

`font-family:Helvetica Neue` is working for me [here is the link](https://jsfiddle.net/z9ocrh4t/7/)

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much! One last question before I accept the answer and upvote, how can I change the family-font of placeholder and typed text inside?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this code down. Your error was that you forgot to put a colon.

I put a lot of time in this, but it all comes down to putting another colon after `:-webkit-input-placeholder`, making it `::-webkit-input-placeholder`.

I just discovered someone else answered the same exact way I did, and I don't mean to copy them, because I figured this out myself.

Take a look at the complete code. PS I made it look cursive for `font-family`.

```css
#input-field {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px;
  color: red;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-family: cursive;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: blue;
  font-family: cursive;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input className="form-control" id="input-field" placeholder='Change This Color' />
```

Comment: how can I change the family-font of placeholder and typed text inside?

Comment: Had to do minor changes but got it to work. Thank you!